# Custom Error Messages and `required_without_all` validation anomaly in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, forms, validation, laravel-5.1

**Here are the facts:**

- I have a form with many fields
- For three of the fields, I only require one of them to be filled
- I have set `required_without_all:` in my custom form request for these three fields
- I have modified the `:attribute` in `validation.php` for my required fields
- The form fields in question are unique within my application

**Here are the issues:**

- When I enter a phone number in the `emerg_contact_home_phone` field, the other two do not display the error, which is correct.
- When I enter a phone number in the `emerg_contact_work_phone` field, the `emerg_contact_mobile_phone` displays an error.
- When I enter a phone number in the `emerg_contact_mobile_phone` field, both the `emerg_contact_home_phone` AND `emerg_contact_work_phone` display an error.
- When the error messages display, `emerg_contact_mobile_phone` doesn't display the modified attribute "Mobile Phone", it displays "emerg_contact_mobile_phone" instead.

**Here is what I've tried:**

- I have triple checked the spelling of the form names in all locations.
- I firmly believe the issue has to do with the `emerg_contact_mobile_phone` field, so I tried changing the name to something different (ie: 'mobile_phone')

**Here is my code:**

form.blade.php:

```
        <tr>
            <td class="col-md-4">
                {!! Form::label('emerg_contact_work_phone', '* Work Phone:', array('class' => 'control-label')) !!}
            </td>
            <td class="{{ $errors->has('emerg_contact_work_phone') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
                {!! Form::text('emerg_contact_work_phone', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
                {!! $errors->first('emerg_contact_work_phone', '<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="col-md-4">
                {!! Form::label('emerg_contact_home_phone', '* Home Phone:', array('class' => 'control-label')) !!}
            </td>
            <td class="{{ $errors->has('emerg_contact_home_phone') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
                {!! Form::text('emerg_contact_home_phone', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
                {!! $errors->first('emerg_contact_home_phone', '<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="col-md-4">
                {!! Form::label('emerg_contact_mobile_phone', '* Mobile Phone:', array('class' => 'control-label')) !!}
            </td>
            <td class="{{ $errors->has('emerg_contact_mobile_phone') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
                {!! Form::text('emerg_contact_mobile_phone', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
                {!! $errors->first('emerg_contact_mobile_phone', '<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
            </td>
        </tr>
```

validation.php:

```
'attributes' => [
    'givenname' => 'First Name',
    'surname' => 'Last Name',
    'email' => 'Email',
    'emerg_contact_relationship' => 'Relationship',
    'emerg_contact_givenname' => 'First Name',
    'emerg_contact_surname' => 'Last Name',
    'emerg_contact_work_phone' => 'Work Phone',
    'emerg_contact_home_phone' => 'Home Phone',
    'emerg_contact_mobile_phone' => 'Mobile Phone',
],
```

CustomFormRequest.php:

```
    public function rules()
{
    return [
        'givenname' => 'required',
        'surname' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:employees,email,' . $this->get('id'),
        'password' => 'required_with:is_user|min:6',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required_with:is_user|min:6|same:password',
        'aca_number' => 'unique:employees,aca_number,' . $this->get('id'),
        'license_number' => 'unique:employees,license_number,' . $this->get('id'),
        'base_location' => 'required',
        'emerg_contact_relationship' => 'required',
        'emerg_contact_givenname' => 'required',
        'emerg_contact_surname' => 'required',
        'emerg_contact_home_phone' => 'required_without_all:emerg_contact_work_phone, emerg_contact_mobile_phone',
        'emerg_contact_work_phone' => 'required_without_all:emerg_contact_home_phone, emerg_contact_mobile_phone',
        'emerg_contact_mobile_phone' => 'required_without_all:emerg_contact_home_phone, emerg_contact_work_phone',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Just to try, to taking out the spaces between the comma and the next column. `emerg_contact_work_phone,emerg_contact_mobile_phone`

Comment: holy mother...good catch!! Better submit that as an answer :)

Comment: Ha! I wasn't actually sure if it was the case, but all the examples don't use spaces.

Comment: bad habit I guess...coding isn't like writing a sentence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns should be comma separated without a space:

```
'emerg_contact_home_phone' => 'required_without_all:emerg_contact_work_phone,emerg_contact_mobile_phone',
```